# how to show infowindow in google map mvc

Tags: c#, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

i am show the info window but not show the info window..how to resolve this problem..
only show the title .but .not show the info window..
only show the title .but .not show the info window..

@model  IEnumerable

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Show/Add multiple markers to Google Maps in asp.net website</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .infowindow
        {
            background-color: Yellow;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 0px, 0px, 0px, 0px;
            margin: 0px, 0px, 0px, 0px;
        }

        #map_canvas {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6v5-2uaq_wusHDktM9ILcqIrlPtnZgEk&sensor=false">
    </script>

    <script>
        CMS.Maps.map.setZoom(40);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">



        function initialize() {

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                center: { lat: 31.491390, lng: 74.299242 },
                zoom: 12,

            });

            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.reload();
            }, 60000);

            var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
            $.each(model, function (index, item) {
                var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
                var name = item.Name;


                var point = { lat: Number(item.Lati), lng: Number(item.Longi)};
                var contentString = '<div class="infowindow"><p>' + item.Lati + '<br/>' + item.Lagi+ '</p></div>';

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: point,
                    icon: image,
                    title: name,



                });



                marker.setMap(map);
            });
        }
        // Create our info window content   
        var infoWindowContent = '<div class="info_content">' +
            '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
            '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +
        '</div>';
        // Initialise the inforWindow
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: infoWindowContent
        });


(function(marker, item) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {

        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });

})(marker, item);


    </script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <form id="form1">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 900px; height: 600px"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

An [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#introduction) displays content (usually text or images) in a popup window above the map, at a given location. The info window has a content area and a tapered stem. The tip of the stem is attached to a specified location on the map.

The content of the `InfoWindow` may contain a string of text, a snippet of HTML, or a DOM element. To set the content, either specify it within the `InfoWindowOptions` or call `setContent()` on the `InfoWindow` explicitly.

If you wish to explicitly size the content, you can put it in a `<div>` element and style the `<div>` with CSS. You can use CSS to enable scrolling too. Note that if you do not enable scrolling and the content exceeds the space available in the info window, the content may spill out of the info window.

You can check this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) on how to use info window. Just take note that this example is using javascript.

Comment: m using google example..with out database values  is working..if add the databse values then infowindow is not working..